# Can I add or substract jQuery values and JavaScript values?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, nan

```
function moves_like_jagger(event) {
var MouseX=event.clientX;
for(i=1;i<l+1;i++) {
    helper=".d"+i;
    amount=(MouseX-$(this).width/2)*layer[i-1];
}}
```

The problem with this occurs when the jQuery thing comes in. In this case I want to use jQuery to access id,class, etc. but when I run this script and write "amount" with document.write(amount) I get NaN... I tested it, its because of the jQuery. `$(this).width` gives back no numbers but a script instead. What is the problem?

Comment: Always the first thing to do: **Read the documentation** (http://api.jquery.com/width/)!. And FWIW, there is no such thing as a "jQuery value". jQuery is a **library** written in JavaScript. Everything is either an object, array, function, string, number, etc.

Comment: sorry for being thick, Im not a web programmer or whatever, just got an idea and tried to make it somehow...

Answer (score 1):

> "$(this).width" gives back no numbers but a script instead. What is the problem?

The `width` property of a jQuery object is a Function, not a Number.

Call it, and use its return value instead.

Answer (score 1):

that's because jQuery.width() is a function, not a property. Change

```
amount=(MouseX-$(this).width/2)*layer[i-1];
```

to

```
amount=(MouseX-$(this).width()/2)*layer[i-1];
```